# Pseudo-code for Network-only-bayes-classifier

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, igraph, pseudocode, naivebayes

I am trying to implement a classification toolkit for univariate network data using `igraph` and `python`.

However, my question is actually more of an algorithms question in relational classification area instead of programming.

I am following [Classification in Networked Data](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume8/macskassy07a/macskassy07a.pdf) paper.

I am having a difficulty to understand what this paper refers to "*Network-Only Bayes Classifier*"(NBC) which is one of the relational classifiers explained in the paper.

I implemented `Naive Bayes` classifier for text data using bag of words feature representation earlier. And the idea of `Naive Bayes` on text data is clear on my mind.

I think this method (NBC) is a simple translation of the same idea to the relational classification area. However, I am confused with the notation used in the equations, so I couldn't figure out what is going on. I also have a question on the notation used in the paper [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331159/terminology-the-difference-between-xs-convention).

NBC is explained in page 14 on [the paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume8/macskassy07a/macskassy07a.pdf),

[image]

**Summary:**

I need the pseudo-code of the "*Network-Only Bayes Classifier*"(NBC) explained in the [paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume8/macskassy07a/macskassy07a.pdf), page 14.

**Pseudo-code notation:**

1. Let's call `vs` the list of vertices in the graph. `len(vs)` is the
   length. `vs[i]` is the ith vertex.
2. Let's assume we have a univariate and binary scenario, i.e., `vs[i].class` is either `0` or `1` and there is no other given feature of a node.
3. Let's assume we run a local classifier before so that every node has an initial label, which are calculated by the local classifier. I am only interested in with the relational classifier part.
4. Let's call `v` the vertex we are trying to predict, and `v.neighbors()` is the list of vertices which are neighbors of `v`.
5. Let's assume all the edge weights are `1`.

Now, I need the pseudo-code for:

```
def NBC(vs, v):
   # v.class is 0 or 1
   # v.neighbors is list of neighbor vertices
   # vs is the list of all vertices

   # This function returns 0 or 1
```

**Edit:**

To make your job easier, I did this [example](http://saitcelebi.com/drawing.pdf). I need the answer for last 2 equations.

Comment: Well laid out question. I am following with interest (if not an actual answer ;) )

Answer (score 3):

In words...

The probability that node `x_i` belongs to the class `c` is equal to:

- The probability of the neighbourhood of `x_i` (called `N_i`) if `x`
  belonged indeed to the class `c`; Multiplied by ...
- The probability of the class `c` itself; Divided by ...
- The probability of the neighbourhood `N_i` (of node `x_i`) itself.

As far as the probability of the neighbourhood `N_i` (of `x_i`) if `x` were to belong to the class `c` is concerned, it is equal to:

- A [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation) of some probability; (which probability?)
- The probability that some node (`v_j`) of the neighbourhood (`N_i`) belongs to the class `c` if `x` belonged indeed to the class `c`

  - (raised to the weight of the edge connecting the node that is being examined and the node that is being classified...but you are not interested in this...yet). (The notation is a bit off here I think, why do they define `v_j` and then never use it?...Whatever).
- Finally, multiply the `product of some probability` with some `1/Z`. Why? Because all `p`s are [probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability#Mathematical_treatment) and therefore lie within the range of 0 to 1, but the weights `w` could be anything, meaning that in the end, the calculated probability could be out of range.
- The probability that some `x_i` belongs to a class `c` GIVEN THE
  EVIDENCE FROM ITS NEIGHBOURHOOD, is a *posterior* probability. (AFTER
  something...What is this something? ... Please see below)
- The probability of appearance of neighbourhood `N_i` if `x_i`
  belonged to the class `c` is the *likelihood*.
- The probability of the class `c` itself is the *prior probability*.
  BEFORE something...What is this something? The evidence. The prior
  tells you the probability of the class without any evidence
  presented, but the posterior tells you the probability of a specific
  event (that `x_i` belongs to `c`) GIVEN THE EVIDENCE FROM ITS
  NEIGHBOURHOOD.

The *prior*, can be subjective. That is, derived by limited observations OR be an informed opinion. In other words, it doesn't have to be a population distribution. It only has to be accurate enough, not absolutely known.

The *likelihood* is a bit more challenging. Although we have here a formula, the likelihood must be estimated from a large enough population or as much "physical" knowledge about the phenomenon being observed as possible.

Within the product (capital letter Pi in the second equation that expresses the *likelihood*) you have a conditional. The conditional is the probability that a neighbourhood node belongs to some class if `x` belonged to class `c`.

In the typical application of the [Naive Bayesian Classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), that is [document classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Document_classification) (e.g. spam mail), the conditional that `an email is spam GIVEN THE APPEARANCE OF SPECIFIC WORDS IN ITS BODY` is **derived** by a huge database of observations, or, a huge database of emails that we **really, absolutely know** which class they belong to. In other words, I must have an idea of how does a spam email looks like and eventually, **the majority** of spam emails converge to having some common theme (I am some bank official and i have a money opportunity for you, give me your bank details to wire money to you and make you rich...).

Without this knowledge, we can't use Bayes rule.

So, to get back to your specific problem. In your PDF, you have a question mark in the derivation of the product.

Exactly.

So the real question here is: What is the *likelihood* from your Graph / data?

(...**or** Where are you going to derive it from? (obviously, either a large number of known observations **OR** some knowledge about the phenomenon. For example, what is the likelihood that a node is **infected** given that a proportion of its neighbourhood is infected too)).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It was helpful. However, I was actually looking for a `pseudo-code`.